# Specific Regular Expression In Javascript with a condition

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

How to format a regular expression In JavaScript :

```
http://localhost:3000/sales?&tp=Home+Stay&am=Pool&pl=1620&pt=Flash+Sale&st=5
```

I want to get **&pl=** and all the digits after **&pl=**.
So the result would be &pl=1620 in this case.
Please help how to perform this?? 
Your help means a lot for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will do the trick:

```
var regex = /&pl=\d*/;
var match = regex.exec(yourtext)[0];
```

Comment: ok, how I will assign it to Variable , because after it I want to split using that variable. for example => if I write var num = &pl=\d* then  it gives a syntax error. Please help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. LeviBotelho.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should do it

```
/&pl=\d*/.exec('http://localhost:3000/sales?&tp=Home+Stay&am=Pool&pl=1620&pt=Flash+Sale&st=5')[0]
```

Demo: [Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bc4MG/)